# What is component decorator `queries` property for

Tags: angular

I'm looking [at this page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html) that lists all `@Component` decorator properties and there is the following:

> queries - configure queries that can be injected into the component

I've tried googling but there is not much on the web. What's it used for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its practically the same as the `@ViewChild`, `@ViewChildren`, `@ContentChild`, `@ContentChildren` decorators, but you can define them inside the metadata.

See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/12.1.1/packages/core/src/metadata/directives.ts#L221-L258

Comment: thanks, I'm wondering when I should use `queries` and what they can be configured to besides `new ContentChildren(ChildDirective)`

Comment: As far as i know you can only use: `new ContentChildren(selector) new ContentChild(selector) new ViewChildren(selector) new ViewChild(selector)`

Comment: thanks, so I shouldn't use them because I get the same with `@ViewChild, @ViewChildren, @ContentChild, @ContentChildren`? Or I can write my own queries?

Comment: You could use them, i think they're working practically the same as the decorators. Maybe i'm wrong but its just up to personal preference how to declare your queries.

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll try my luck asing on angular github, but they don't usually respond :(